# How to do frame-based updating in a HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, coffeescript

I'm trying to make a simple Coffeescript thing which is kinda like [Createjs](http://www.createjs.com/). What it does is has functions which make drawing things on a canvas easier. The problem is updating the canvas. At the moment, I'm using `window.setInterval` to do something every 1/60th of a second, but that's very unreliable as the framerate changes randomly between about 40FPS and 65FPS. In createjs, it makes a fairly reliable FPS and only goes above the target FPS by at most 1.

So, what's the best way to do this and if anybody can explain, how des createjs do it?

Comment: look into Window.requestAnimationFrame()

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll have a look

Comment: @user2950720 I don't really get it, could you try and explain?

Comment: @user2950720 Actually, I got it working so I'll accept your answer if you post it as an actual answer